# Windows Shutdown - Shutdown command or ExitWindowsEx

Tags: windows, winapi, shutdown

I want to know which is the best practice when a piece of software needs to restart, shutdown, logoff or hibernate Windows:

1. Use **ExitWindowsEx** API
2. Use **Shutdown** command and its parameters

What is the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Thanks

Comment: user can still issue `shutdown /a` to cancel a shutdown if the `shutdown` action is being countdown.

Comment: @saenold: Noooo My question is regarding a piece of software which is giving the user the option to click a button to shutdown Windows.

Comment: Shelling to external code should always be a last resort.  If there's an API, and you can use it, use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always prefer calling the API (`ExitWindowsEx`, `InitiateSystemShutdown`).

Pro API

- GetLastError can be used to diagnose errors
- You get access to the full API, not just the things exposed by a utility
- You don't have to worry about filesystem redirection and whether the tool exists in the home versions of Windows
- The documented interface stays the same, command line switches could change or be different in a different language

Pro external tool

- Makes some difficult tasks easy to perform (Some things require undocumented API's)
- Few bugs, and if there are bugs they are not yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

They are different.

Using API, you can apply more logic in your program, e.g. get the current state, etc.

Using the command, you can just perform the actions.

Comment: You are totally right, but in a situation that user decides to shutdown or not, which approach is better? I mean which approach is more successful at all situations including when the user is not `administrator`

Comment: API suits your need, which give you full control on shutdown process.