# how to force shutdown computer using cpp program

Tags: c++, winapi, shutdown

i have been working on a small project. i am making a timer for my little brother's PC so that he will not be able to use computer more than set time by me in a day.
The problem I am facing in my code is I have tried bunch of system commands to shut down computer automatically but when it runs the command it asks to wether close the running applications. but I want to force shut down all running apps. below is the code i am trying but it is not quite working out

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\shutdown /s /t 0");
```

now this statement, when it is executed, asks for closing applications which are running or cancel shut down process

```
ExitWindowsEx(EWX_SHUTDOWN | EWX_FORCE,
    SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OPERATINGSYSTEM |
    SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_UPGRADE |
    SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED);
```

i got this above function from Microsoft docs but it doesn't work in my computer even it doesn't show any error in this statement. but even after executing it doesn't work. moreover visual studio offered its own suggestion of using a new API which is given below

```
InitiateSystemShutdownEx(NULL, NULL, 0, true, false, SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_USER_DEFINED);
```

this also doesn't work even if gets execute. i am using windows 11. and below i am giving the whole code where i reached yet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<fstream>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")
using namespace std;


void timer()
{
    int hours=0;
    int minutes=0;
    int seconds=0;
    ofstream tim;
    while (seconds != 5)
    {
        tim.open("time.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
        seconds++;
        Sleep(1000);
        if (seconds == 60)
        {
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
        if (minutes == 60)
        {
            hours++;
            minutes = 0;
        }
        tim << hours << endl << minutes << endl << seconds;
        tim.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    timer();
    ExitWindowsEx(EWX_SHUTDOWN | EWX_FORCE,
        SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OPERATINGSYSTEM |
        SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_UPGRADE |
        SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED);
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

so please just any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) Since you're using C++, you'd be better off using the tools in [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) to implement your time-conversion logic as well as your sleep operation. Simpler code. (2) ExitWindowsEx and/or InitiateSystemShutdownEx are the APIs you should be calling. Avoid using the `system` function; there's never a good use for this. (3) Note that this operation (shutting down a computer) requires elevated privileges. Are you running this app as an administrator? (Technically, you need the `SE_SHUTDOWN` privilege.) Call GetLastError to find out why it fails.

Comment: Here's some helpful reading on programmatic solutions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-functions

Comment: Hopefully your end result will be a bit friendlier and give a warning so he can save what he's doing. Personally I'm rooting for the little dude to find all the ways to disable this and keep you on your toes.

Comment: @RetiredNinja haha it was a gud one...but this little dude is always playing games and never studying....he never uses computer or internet to learn something creative or productive even though I tried so much to make his time useful....so its better he give less time to computer and more to family and studies and his real world games and friends rather than just playing fortnite or pubg for 10 hours....

Comment: @mueeburrehman Blindly shutting down his computer is not the best way to handle this. Using a firewall, or even an external device like [Circle](https://meetcircle.com/), to block unwanted content and allow desirable content would be a far better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `/f` flag to force a shutdown.

Comment: Although this may work and solve the immediate problem, it is worth noting (if nothing else, for future readers) that it is *vastly* preferable to call the documented API, rather than to shell out to a helper program. Some reasons are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371152). The correct APIs to use in this case are `ExitWindowsEx` or `InitiateSystemShutdownEx`. There is never a case where using the `system` function to invoke `shutdown /f` would work, but the correct APIs would not work, unless you're mis-calling the APIs.

Comment: @CodyGray u r right in ur place but I gotta mark that answer which worked for me obviously...i am in favor of ur answer too because in whole web I saw the examples of API and I also prefer using them...thanks for illustration brother

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual logoff function I created many years ago when faced with a similar problem.  There's a lot of extra code there to support debugging without logging myself out, the actual work is in the call to `ExitWindowsEx`.

```
void CTimeLimitApp::Logoff()
{
    static bool bOff = false;
    if (bOff)
        return;
    bOff = true;
#if _DEBUG
    AfxMessageBox("Logoff!", MB_OK, 0);
    PostQuitMessage(0);
#else
    Sleep(1000);
    ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF | EWX_FORCE, 0);
#endif
}
```

You may need to run the program as Administrator if you want to do a full shutdown.

Comment: `_DEBUG` is a Visual Studio defined by default for any debug build. It's hard to upvote an answer where the code has a drastically different behavior between release and debug builds. If you really feel a "dry fun" branch is necessary to answer the question, consider using a different preprocessor macro to toggle the behavior independently of the choice of release/debug build configuration.

Comment: C++11 introduced [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) as an alternative to solutions such as `bOff`. It provides a solution to that is thread safe and exception safe.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you don't need to upvote an answer if you feel it doesn't deserve it.  As I said, this is the actual code I used and I thought that copy/paste the whole thing might prove useful to somebody.  I really really didn't want to accidentally lose my work while I was fine tuning the program.

Comment: @fra [Static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) are thread-safe starting with C++11. The exception safety that `std::call_once` provides doesn't apply here: The code is strictly calling into C functions, and while those generally provide the basic exception safety guarantee, the way failure is communicated is incompatible with C++' exceptions. This isn't to say that one *shouldn't* use `std::call_once` here, but the reason is a different one: Documentation of intent.

Comment: @IInspectable Threadsafe static local variable initialization isn't enough to make the approach thread safe. This is a C++11 "gotcha". If this function can be called concurrently, `bOff` would still have to be synchronized. My 2nd comment is general advice to anyone who would find this code. Regarding documenting intent, I am of the opinion that `std::call_once` is the clearest way to self-document that the implementer expected a function to only be called once, the argument seems to me like a good reason to switch to `std::call_once`, and not an argument for keeping the solution shown.

Comment: @fra That's true, initialization of statics is thread-safe, but modification isn't. That'd still require something along the lines of [`std::atomic_flag::test_and_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test_and_set).